# Specifying a moment in the future when something will happen

Tags: future, future-perfect

Is one of these phrases correct:

> as soon as I earn enough money
>   as soon as I have earned enough money
>   as soon as I'll earn enough money
>   as soon as I'll have earned enough money

or are all wrong?

I want to point to a moment in the future when I'll have some/enough money to purchase something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are correct:

> as soon as I earn enough money
>    as soon as I have earned enough money

and these aren't:

> as soon as I'll earn enough money
>   as soon as I'll have earned enough money

You don't need the *will* when using *as soon as*.

Comment: What's the major difference between "indefinite" and "perfect" in these particular phrases then?

Comment: Note that you will want the *will* later on, e.g. *As soon as I earn enough money, I **will** buy myself a motorboat.*

Comment: @drɱ65 δ: thanks, but any comments about difference between indefinite and perfect in this case? Or are they just interchangeable?

Comment: The meanings in this context are the same; they are interchangeable.